# Replace html from one element to another in different html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to replace the contents of one element with the contents of another element in a different html file.

I have seen many JS & JQ functions to do this to elements in the same html file using `document.getElementById` and `$(this)` etc., but can this replace the contents of one element to another element in a separate html file? Below is an example of my problem.

pageOne.html file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <title>Page 1</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#first").click(function() {
                    $("#second").html($(this).html());
                 });
            });
        </script>
            <body>
                <p id = "first">Hello</p>
                <a href="pageTwo.html" target="_self">Page 2</a>
            </body>
    </html>
```

pageTwo.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <title>Page 2</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <body>
                <p id = "second">World!</p>
                <a href="pageOne.html" target="_self">Page 1</a>
            </body>
    </html>
```

I have tried different ways to do this like the following but I am just not getting it:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                document.getElementById("#second").innerHTML = #first;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
        <body>
            <p id = "first" onclick = "myFunction()">Hello</p>
        </body>
</html>
```

Is this possible so when you click on the #first element it replaces the content in #second element with the #first element content which is in another html file? So when you click between pages the content of `<p>` will be the same.

Comment: Are the two files loaded in the same html page with iframes? Are they in separate windows?

Comment: With ajax and SocketIO like library needed.

Comment: As long as you are not displaying both pages simultaneously (as @Mario asked, are they in iframes/different tabs?), you can't do that with client-side JavaScript at all.

Comment: Javascript doesn't operate on files, it manipulates the DOM, which is an object that represents the page that's currently being displayed in the browser.

Comment: If the pages are loaded in different tabs, I mean browser tabs, you can use Storage Events to communicate between them. Take a look at this [demo](http://html5demos.com/storage-events)

Comment: You can look at using [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load the HTML from the second file and then pull the appropriate node from the response...

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called Tabbed Contents. If you google you'll find many samples.

Check below links:

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

http://www.menucool.com/tabbed-content

http://inspirationalpixels.com/tutorials/creating-tabs-with-html-css-and-jquery

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that javascript/jQuery can only manipulate elements on the web page (i.e. the web page *as displayed,* the `DOM`). *Thus, it is possible to change things on the rendered page that the user is viewing.* These languages cannot save to either the user's local computer or back to the web server.

HTML `<form>`s can transmit data from one HTML page to another, but they cannot update the `.html` page on the server.

To make changes on the server, you must use a server-side language, such as PHP or asp .Net.

By far the most common is PHP, as it's the "P" in XAMPP, LAMP, WAMP, MAMP, etc. Most of the shared hosting packages available from big hosting companies like GoDaddy, NameCheap, HostGator, etc are LAMP stacks (Linux, Apache, MySQP, PHP). If PHP is installed on your server, all you must do to use it is name the file using extension `.php` instead of `.html`. *In fact, you need never use `.html` again -- every file can be named `.php` and it will work exactly the same as a file that ends `.html` -- except that, if required, it can now process PHP code.*

To use PHP on your own computer, install XAMPP *(available for OSX, Windows and Linux).* Note that the web folder is `c:\xampp\htdocs` and you "see" the web page by type (only) `localhost` into the browser address bar.

[Here is a series of (free) tutorial videos](https://thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=11) about PHP.

---

As I re-read your question, I believe that HTML forms could do what you require. You would need these two files on your webserver: `first.html` and `second.php`

**first.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="second.php" method="post">
            <input name="firstname" type="text" value="Jonathan" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Now">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**second.php**

```
<?php
    $fn = $_POST['firstname'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>You sent the name: <?php echo $fn; ?></p>
    </body>
</html>
```